# mysql корректировать запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь обновить поле, запросом -

```
UPDATE users SET status = {$status} WHERE id = {$id}
```

Но дело в том что выдает ошибку, так как строка status содержит большое количество символов и разрывы строк.

Comment: А какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: Если вы правильно работаете с БД, т.е. используете современные методы (PDO или MySQLi) и привязку переменных, то никакие символы в строке не могут ничего сломать в запросе и единственная ошибка может быть от того, что длины поля не хватает. http://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE users SET status = '{$status}' WHERE id = '{$id}'"
```

попробуйте так

Answer (score 0):

В БД смените тип поля на VARCHAR и задайте длину 100 или как у вас требуется.